# Converting flattened json into nested structure

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a flattened file with the following info

```
A    B     C
5    1     [1,2.....10]
5    1     [11,12,13]
5    2     [1,2,3,15,16]
6    1     [1,2,3]
7    3     [4,5,6,7]
```

which was flattened using

```
explode(arraySlice(col(C), lit(0), lit(10))))
```

I need to aggregate on column B based on column C containing the same value and convert this structure into the format

```
{5, [1,2] , 1}
{5, [1,2] , 2}
{5, [1,2] , 3}
{5, 1 , 4}
.
.
.
{5, 1, 13}
{5, 2, 15}
{5, 2, 16}
{6, 1 , 1}
.
.
.
{7, 3 , 7]}
```

I am using scala on spark. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a dataframe as

```
+---+---+-------------------------------+
|A  |B  |C                              |
+---+---+-------------------------------+
|5  |1  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]|
|5  |1  |[11, 12, 13]                   |
|5  |2  |[1, 2, 3, 15, 16]              |
|6  |1  |[1, 2, 3]                      |
|7  |3  |[4, 5, 6, 7]                   |
+---+---+-------------------------------+
```

You can do explode and aggregation as following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("C", explode(col("C")))
  .groupBy("A", "C")
  .agg(collect_list("B").as("B"))
  .select("A", "B", "C")
  .show(false)
```

and you should get your desired output

```
+---+------+---+
|A  |B     |C  |
+---+------+---+
|5  |[2]   |16 |
|6  |[1]   |1  |
|7  |[3]   |4  |
|5  |[1]   |7  |
|5  |[1]   |6  |
|5  |[1]   |4  |
|5  |[1]   |12 |
|5  |[1]   |13 |
|6  |[1]   |3  |
|7  |[3]   |5  |
|5  |[1]   |10 |
|6  |[1]   |2  |
|5  |[1]   |8  |
|5  |[2]   |15 |
|5  |[1, 2]|2  |
|5  |[1, 2]|1  |
|5  |[1, 2]|3  |
|7  |[3]   |7  |
|5  |[1]   |9  |
|5  |[1]   |11 |
+---+------+---+
```